# ArrayList is empty after method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have something I dont understand. I have a private arrayList and use it in a function and it also gets and stores the values, but only until the method has finished. Any tip where is my error?

```
private ArrayList<MyEventClass> myeventList = new ArrayList<MyEventClass>();

private void get(){
    System.out.println("Size: " + myeventList.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("Size: " + myeventList.toString());

    if(myeventList.isEmpty()) {
        myeventArrayList = downloadEvent();

        for (int position = 0; position < myeventArrayList.size(); position++) {
            MyEventClass currentEvent = new MyEventClass(myeventArrayList.get(position).get("name").toString(), myeventArrayList.get(position).get("location"), myeventArrayList.get(position).get("date")
                    , myeventArrayList.get(position).get("type"), myeventArrayList.get(position).get("theme"), myeventArrayList.get(position).get("link"), Integer.parseInt(myeventArrayList.get(position).get("myevents_ref")));
            myeventList.add(currentEvent);
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Size: " + myeventList.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("Size: " + myeventList.toString());
}
```

Every time I get the same results:

```
Size: true
Size: []
Size: false
Size: [com.hobbyathletes.hobbyathletes.Object.MyEventClass@4218bb60, com.hobbyathletes.hobbyathletes.Object.MyEventClass@4218bfb0, com.hobbyathletes.hobbyathletes.Object.MyEventClass@4218c3b8]
```

Why isnt it the second time the result of isEmpty == true?

Thx
md

Comment: BECAUSE IT IT NOT ... myeventList.add(currentEvent);

Comment: What does `EventAdapter` do with the `List`?

Comment: you have pasted output of something else i.e. i dont see you print myeventclass anywhere in code above. So please correct the code or correct the output. It is possible that your myArrayEventList is empty and hence no element gets added to your myeventlist.

Comment: Well, I create new objects out of the information of a myeventArrayList which later I add to the myeventList. After that I test the myeventList again and it has values, also I work later on with them again in this method. Just when this method as finished, its empty again...

Comment: `isEmpty()` is equivalent in result to `size() <= 0`, aka once you add an element and `size` will be `>= 1`, then `isEmpty()` will return `false` because it is not empty.

Comment: What you just pasted shows it IS working...

Comment: No, because as u can see, there are 4 System outs,  but later when I run this method again, the first System out is true again

Comment: how do you call it ? paste the full class and the full caller please :)

Comment: you added elements to your list, why you expect it to be empty?

Comment: You added some elements, so why should the list be empty in the end?

Comment: please dont laugh: http://codepad.org/bkGe0dkd code is to long

Comment: how do you call it ? if you make a new instance of your class, your Array will be initialized (as you write at line 46)

Comment: the class myevent is only created once. I dont close this one

Comment: wait, i think u are right...I have to check the onCreate method. Will come back later

Comment: I am really sorry. I just thought I was to stupid set a variable and havent even tried thinking about that the instance is recreated by rotating. For the moment I just added this to the manifest: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"